# ElasticSearch: nested aggregation but get the root doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to index some user properties, the user data mondel is like the following, `fxy` are a bunch of properties grouped together under group `gx`

```
User: {
  g1: {
    f11: ...,
    f12: ...,
    f13: ...
  },
  g2: {
    f21: ...,
    f22: ...,
    f23: ...
  }
}
```

So I can get the top N results of `f11` by using nested aggregation

```
{
  "query": {
    ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "l1": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "g1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "l2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "g1.f11"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the response is like

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "l1": {
      "doc_count": .....,
      "l2": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": k1,
            "doc_count": ...
          },
          {
            "key": k2,
            "doc_count": ...
          }
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my problem is that all the `doc_count`s in nested aggregation are numbers of `gx` with `fxy=kz`. Is there any way to get numbers of Users with at least one `gx` satisfying `fxy=kz`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently our workaround is

- duplicate data in nested object to root level object
- query for top N results of `f11`, using nested aggregation first
- apply the top N result back as part of the query filter, then aggregate on first level field.

Which means

changing mapping to

```
User: {
  g1_f11: [],
  g1_f12: [],
  ...
  g2_f21: [],
  g2_f22: [],
  ...,
  g1: {
    f11: ...,
    f12: ...,
    f13: ...
  },
  g2: {
    f21: ...,
    f22: ...,
    f23: ...
  }
}
```

get top N results for field `f11`, then apply as part of the filter, and aggregate on `g1_f11`

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "g1",
      "query": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "g1" {
                "query": "k1"
              }              
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "g1" {
                "query": "k2"
              }              
            }
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "l1": {
      "terms": {
        "fields": "g1_f11"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then the final `doc_count` in aggregation output will be # of users

Answer (score 0):

Found that turns out ElasticSearch does provide a solution: [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html). Which is exactly what we want.